# get_terms('category')

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display the categories with the get_terms function with the following code:

```
$categories = get_terms( 'category');
$categories_count = count($categories);

                    for ($i = 0; $i < $categories_count; $i++) {
                        echo($i . $categories[$i]->name.' <br /> ');
                    }
```

But for some reason doesnt display all the categories, a couple of them are missing uncategorized and something else, this is what I see on the screen when i run this code:

- 0 Chairs
- 1
- 2 Interiors
- 3
- 4 Featured

Thanks very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `get_categories()` instead of `get_terms()`. This is how you should do it:

```
<?php 
    $categories = get_categories(); 
    $number = 1;
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        print $number . $category->cat_name . '<br />';
        $number++;
    }
?>
```

Just give it a shot ...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct as far as I can tell, however the will be an issue in get_terms() OR the terms themselves don't actually have a name.

Comment: They have a name each of them has a post on it, but for some reason it displays like that

Comment: @MariaZ Have you tried using var_dump() in your loop to verify this?

Comment: thanks very much... when i tried var_dump i get null in the empty ones... strange isnt it... i still dont know why,  anyways... the get_categories does what i was looking for...

Answer (score 0):

To display tags and/or categories list:

```
<span>Tags: <?php 
                    global $post;
                    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'your-taxonomy');
                    if ($terms) {
                        $output = array();
                            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                            $output[] = '<a href="' .get_term_link( $term->slug, 'your-taxonomy') .'\*for CPT please add url suffix /?post_types=your_cpt*\">' .$term->name .'</a>';
                            }
                            echo join( ', ', $output );
                                }
                                        ?>

                <span>
```